# Accessing parent fragments methods from recyclerview's adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-recyclerview, rx-java

Hi guys I'm trying to access few methods and variables of fragment(containing a recycler view) from the recycler views adapter class.. Simplest way is to pass in the fragment reference along with the adapter which creating it. But I dont think passing the full adapter reference which creating the adapter is a good approach.

I'm using RxJava in my project and tried a lot of things with PublishSubject like creating a Subject in adapter, calling its onNext which an event is performed and subscribe to that subject in the fragment but it didnt work out..

So any good approach will be highly appreciated.

TIA...

Comment: What about using the Delegate pattern by creating an interface that the Fragment can implement?  The fragment could initialize the adapter with something like `adapter.setDelegate(this)`, and when appropriate the adapter could call methods on the delegate like `if (delegate != null) { delegate.someMethod(); }`

Comment: Dont know the delegate thing, gotta check it out. Moreover as using rxjava so have stopped using interfaces for communication.

Comment: anyone who can help me with the same?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to introduce [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) in your app - pretty elegant way of communication between different components of the app.

Then it'd look like:

`Fragment`:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private EventBus eventBus = EventBus.getDefault();

    RecyclerViewAdapter viewAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        eventBus.register(this);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        if (viewAdapter == null) {
            viewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(eventBus);
        }

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(viewAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused") // invoked by EventBus
    public void onEventMainThread(final DataRefreshedEvent event) {
        // Do something!
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        eventBus.unregister(this);
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

`Adapter`:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    EventBus eventBus;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(EventBus eventBus) {
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
    }

    void sentSomethingToFragment() {
        eventBus.post(new DataRefreshedEvent());
    }

    .....
}
```

Event: `public final class DataRefreshedEvent {}`

And just a note - with [Dagger](http://google.github.io/dagger/), it'd look even better.

I hope, it helps

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is go with interface approach. 
1. Create one interface.
2. Fragment should implement that interface.
3. Pass that interface reference to the adapter.
4. Call the interface method from adapter

So that way you can communicate between fragment and adapter.

Comment: As ugly as this is, it's the best answer.  Sigh.